# Verify S/MIME signature with no certificate included

Tags: digital-signature, smime

Let's sign a file with

```
 $ openssl smime -sign -in file -out file.sign -outform DER -inkey private.pem -signer certificate.pem -nocerts
```

With the option `-no certs` no certificate is included in `file.sign`.

Now if you try to verify `file.sign`:

```
$ openssl smime -verify -in file.sign -inform DER -content file -noverify certificate.pem
```

You get

```
Verification failure
139909488150168:error:2107C080:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_get0_signers:signer certificate not found:pk7_smime.c:466:
```

The example works, if you sign without `-nocerts` of course.

But is there are way to *tell* `openssl verify` how to find the certificate ?

Comment: This isn't really about security concepts, but about how to use openssl. I'm voting to move to StackOverflow.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth: it isn't about programming or development either. Although superuser or perhaps serverfault would probably be better, I've seen plenty of how-to-use openssl (and keytool and certutil etc) here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside: you mean `openssl smime -verify` (or the newer and slightly better `openssl cms -verify`). `openssl verify` is a quite different operation which verifies one or more *cert(s)* against a truststore and optionally a purpose.

From the man page which is on your system if Unixy, or on the web at https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/smime.html (emphasis added):

> -certfile file
>
> Allows additional certificates to be specified. When signing these will be included with the message. **When verifying these will be searched for the signers certificates.** The certificates should be in PEM format.

Comment: This even works with `openssl smime`. Thank you so much. I'm going to post the final commands as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

For your interest, this works. (Credits to user *dave_thompson_085*)

**Sign**:

```
openssl smime -sign -nocerts -in file -out file.sgn -inkey private.pem -signer certificate.pem
```

**Verify**:

```
openssl smime -verify -in file.sgn -noverify -certfile certificate.pem
```

Examine / visualize:

```
openssl cms -in file.sgn -noout -cmsout -print
```

Comment: Since this is not actually an _alternative_ answer, it would be better to edit the accepted answer and add your findings there.